# Opencart 1.5.x (may be 2.0), how to put first/last name on any template (not registered user)

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Checkout page.
Not registered user.
I need to put  first/last user name on custom template (this is custom payment tpl of some small bank).
I now, how do it for registered users, it is easy:

```
$this->data['firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
```

But how to do it for not registerd user?
I can't put first/last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your template will only be displayed after they have placed their order but the order is still in the session?

If this is the case, you can get their details from the payment details (or shipping details depending on which one you want) in the session cookie. 
So it would be something like:

```
$this->data['firstname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['payment']['firstname'];
```

Comment: This is true:
`echo ($this->data['firstname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['payment']['firstname']);`
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is true too:

```
echo ($this->data['firstname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['firstname']); 
echo ($this->data['lastname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['lastname']); 
echo ($this->data['email'] = $this->session->data['guest']['email']); 
echo ($this->data['telephone'] = $this->session->data['guest']['telephone']);
```